# Wget and Curl in cron job arent executing javascript in the destinated URL

Tags: javascript, curl, cron, wget, jobs

Good morning community

I am developing a cron job that is intended to run a website every minute of the day. The problem is that when I run the wget or curl in the cron job, it seems that it ignores that all code in JavaScript that is in the page. I know because this same code should send broadcast messages to mobile devices that I have registered and this inst happening.

Have any idea what might be happened? Thx

Comment: What makes you think `wget` or `curl` will interpret (or even fetch) the Javascript resources in the first place?

Comment: My own ignorance of the tool. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run javascript via `wget` or `curl`. Javascript is a browser language, and `wget`/`curl` just getting a raw format of your page.

This mean, the `wget`/`curl` download just a copy of your page (*including javascript if this is in the save file requested by the curl/wget*) but dose not execute it.

Comment: ok, in now days it is more than a browser language, it is just an amazing language, but my answer points to give the Fingolricks the message

Comment: I got the way of doing what I needed in PHP. But your answer was enough guidance as to realize I was not going in the right direction. Thank you